CSS custom cursors AND pointer events WITHOUT flicker?
I'm working on an HTML5 game, and I want to use custom cursors that utilize my game's color palate. I have something like this:
html {
    cursor: url('../assets/cursor_arrow.png'), auto;
}

However, if a user hovers over a button, the cursor immediately reverts to the default (non-custom) one. So then I did this:
html, button:hover {
    cursor: url('../assets/cursor_arrow.png'), auto;
}

And that almost solves it, except there is a brief flicker where the cursor reverts to the default before changing to the custom one whenever entering the button hover state for the first time.
If I do this:
html {
    cursor: url('../assets/cursor_arrow.png'), auto;
}

button {
    pointer-events: none;
}

Then now the cursor is flicker-free when hovering over the button, but now the button really isn't a button anymore as I can't hook into onclick events and such.
Any way to work around this issue (javascript or otherwise)?

Why not button {     cursor: url('../assets/cursor_arrow.png'), auto; } or even * {     cursor: url('../assets/cursor_arrow.png'), auto; }

Because... hmm wow I thought I had tried that. Apparently I've just been staring at the problem too long; that worked perfectly, thanks!
